# Undefined returned while accessing data of another model of loopback from remote method?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

```js
    var loopback = require('loopback');
    var serviceOffering = loopback.getModelByType('ServiceOffering');
    var app = require('../../server/server.js');

    module.exports = function (serviceOffering) {

        serviceOffering.GetAllOfferings = function (options,category,callback) {
            var filter = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(category));
             var arry=[];
             var getOrgFil={where:{or:[]}};
             var uniqOrList=[];

             serviceOffering.find(options,filter, function (err, result) {
     
               for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var obj = result[i];
                   if (arry.indexOf(result[i]._createdBy) === -1) {
                     arry.push(obj._createdBy);
                     getOrgFil.where.or.push({UserName:obj._createdBy});
                    }
                }
                console.log(getOrgFil);
                serviceOffering.app.models.Realm.find(options,getOrgFil, function (err, resl) {
                console.log(resl);
                          return callback(null, resl); 
                });
            });
             
        };

        serviceOffering.remoteMethod(
            'GetAllOfferings', {
                http: { path: '/GetAllOfferings', verb: 'get' },
                accepts: { arg: 'category', type: 'object',http: { source: 'query' }  },
                returns: { type: 'array', root: true }
            });
    }
```

I am making a call to 'Realm' model from my 'ServiceOffering' model's remote method to filter and get some data. But the response i am getting for resp is "undefined". I am new to loopback and have very limited idea on how to debug. I was able to print "result", "getOrgFil", but "resp" comes as 'undefined'. Can someone please help me understand why am i getting 'undefined' when i am trying to get the value of resp via the remote method?

```js
 I get output as mentioned below   

result = [ { SeriviceCategory: 'SCCER',
             AssetType: List [ 'ATCOF', 'ATHUS', 'ATMLK' ],
             ServiceType: List [ 'STQCR' ],
             Identity: null,
             _type: 'ServiceOffering',
             _createdBy: 'admin',
             _modifiedBy: 'admin',
             _createdOn: 2018-01-01T09:21:48.638Z,
             _modifiedOn: 2018-01-01T09:21:48.638Z,
             _scope: List [ 'tenantId:default' ],
             _autoScope: { tenantId: 'default' },
             _isDeleted: false,
             _version: '536c3db2-2323-4004-afb6-2a9e7995aeca',
            id: 5a49fdac28a2bd802d8206ba } ]

getOrgFil =  { where: { or: [ [Object] ] } }
stringified getOrgFil =  {"where":{"or":[{"UserName":"admin"}]}}

resl =   undefined
```

There is no relationship between Realm & ServiceOffering Models.

Comment: what does the realm call back console.log print

Answer (score 0):

It will be this

```
var app = require('../../server/server');

app.models.Realm.find(options,getOrgFil, function (err, resl) { // this instead of serviceOffering.app.models
                          return callback(null, resl); 
                });
```

Comment: nope.. i tried it earlier.. it throws error as :- Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'Realm' of undefined

Comment: then the only thing that might be the cause is that you might not have registered it  as a model in the modelconfig.json properties

Comment: @N29 i have quite the same problem, did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @hajn no i worked around it. Did not quite get a solution for this. Did you get any ?

Comment: @N29 unfortunately I can't remember anymore, but I think I also worked around it